# I'm asked to differentiate this $\dfrac{C}{2} \sum^{m}_{j' = 1} \| W^{j'} \|^{2}_{2}$ but I barely understand the notation.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, normed-spaces, machine-learning

I'm asked to differentiate

$$\dfrac{C}{2} \sum^{m}_{j' = 1} \| W^{j'} \|^{2}_{2},$$

according to $w^{j'}_{k}$ which is the $k$th weight of the vector of weight of $j'$.

- It seems that $\| W^{j'} \|^{2}_{2}$ stands for the the $L2$ norm squared. This seems to indicate that we have:
  $$\| W^{j'} \|^{2}_{2} = w^{2}_1 + w^{2}_2 + ... + w^{2}_k$$
- Then to my understanding $\sum^{m}_{j' = 1} \| W^{j'} \|^{2}_{2}$ seems to indicate that we have:
  $$\sum^{m}_{j' = 1} \| W^{j'} \|^{2}_{2} = (w^{2}_1 + w^{2}_2 + ... + w^{2}_k)_{j'=1} + (w^{2}_1 + w^{2}_2 + ... + w^{2}_k)_{j'=2} + ... + (w^{2}_1 + w^{2}_2 + ... + w^{2}_k)_{j'=m}$$

I have absolutely no clue how to derivate this formula.
Do I use the sum rule to get this?
$$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial w^{j'}_{k}} =\dfrac{C}{2} (2w_k)_{j'=1} + (2w_k)_{j'=2}  + ... + (2w_k)_{j'=m}$$

Edit:
This is from my machine learning course. This formula represents the regularization term we add to the loss function of an SVM (Support vector machines) in order to minimize the objective function.

Here $W$ is a vector containing scalars $w$.

Comment: Differentiate is a better word to use than derivate FWIW.

Comment: I think your answer is actually fine : both what you make of the initial formula, and how you differentiate it after that. Just to be sure , could you provide a link of which document you are reading this material from? If it is class notes, then kindly provide photos, anything to give further context. Also mention which course you are taking ,and what is your background.

Comment: Please supply the definition of $W$. Is it a vector, matrix, etc? What do you mean by "according to $w_k^{j'}$"? Note that $j'$ is a summation index..

Comment: @jack I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: If $W$ is a vector and $j$ is an integer, then what is $W^j$ supposed to mean?

Comment: @Servaes We have multiple vectors W. So $W^j$ is the jth vector. We have m vectors.

Comment: Ok clear. And with respect to which variable are you differentiating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $m$ vectors $W^1,\ldots,W^m$, each of length $n$. So all in all you have $mn$ variables $w^j_k$ with $1\leq j\leq m$ and $1\leq k\leq n$. By definition of the $L^2$-norm you have
$$\frac{C}{2}\sum_{j=1}^m||W^j||_2^2=\frac{C}{2}\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^n(w^j_k)^2,$$
which is simply a sum of squares. So for any particular variable $w^j_k$ you have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w^j_k}(w^i_l)^2=\begin{cases}2w^j_k&\text{ if $i=j$ and $l=k$}\\0&\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$
Then by linearity of derivatives it quickly follows that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w^j_k}\frac{C}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m||W^i||_2^2=\frac{C}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{l=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial w^j_k}(w^i_l)^2=Cw^j_k.$$

Comment: Why does the power of 2 disappear while doing the sum of all the (w)^2?

Comment: What power of $2$ do you mean?

Comment: In the final answer of the derivative where did the 2 in 2w^j_k went?Is Cw inside the \sum or outside? I suspect inside because you kept the indices j and k.

Comment: Ah, I see now. It cancels against the denominator of $\frac{C}{2}$. The rest of the sum vanishes; see the line above.

Comment: I also noticed I overloaded the symbols $j$ and $k$; I used the for both the specific variable $w^j_k$, w.r.t. which we are differentiating, and for the indices of the sums in the last line. I have corrected this now.

Comment: Thank you now it's clear! It seems that I can only give you the bounty points in 53 mins.

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard basis vectors $\{e_k\}$ to extract the columns of the matrix, i.e.
$$W^j = We_j$$
Let's also use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
Then the objective function can be expressed in a form which is friendlier to matrix algebra.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \dfrac{C}{2} \sum^{m}_{j' = 1} \| W^{j'} \|^{2}_{2} \\
 &= \tfrac 12C\left(\sum_{j=1}^m We_j:We_j\right) \\
 &= \tfrac 12C\left(\sum_{j=1}^m e_je_j^T:W^TW\right) \\
 &= \tfrac 12C\Big(I:W^TW\Big) \\
 &= \tfrac 12C\,W:W \\
}$$
Now calculating the gradient is easy.
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= \tfrac 12C\,(W:dW+dW:W) \\
 &= CW:dW \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W} &= CW \\
}$$
If you wish to extract individual components, simply pre/post multiply
by the basis vectors.
$$\eqalign{
e_i^T\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W}\right)e_j &= Ce_i^TWe_j \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W_{ij}} &= CW_{ij} \\
}$$